# Athena returns returning zero result

Tags: amazon-web-services, partitioning, aws-glue, amazon-athena

Hi I am creating a table like -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `historyrecordjson`(
  `last_name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `first_name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `email` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `country` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `city` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `event_time` bigint COMMENT 'from deserializer'
)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `account_id` string, 
  `year` string, 
  `month` string, 
  `day` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://aguptahistoryrecordcopy/recordshistoryjson/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'projection.account_id.type'='injected', 
  'projection.day.range'='01,31', 
  'projection.day.type'='integer', 
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.month.range'='01,12', 
  'projection.month.type'='integer', 
  'projection.year.range'='2020,3000', 
  'projection.year.type'='integer', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://aguptahistoryrecordcopy/historyrecordjson/${account_id}/${year}/${month}/${day}')
```

When I am running below query, it is returning zero record-

```
SELECT * FROM "historyrecordjson" where account_id='acc-1234' AND year= '2021' AND month= '1' AND day='1' limit 10 ;
```

My S3 directory looks like-

```
s3://aguptahistoryrecordcopy/historyrecordjson/account_id=acc-1234/year=2021/month=1/day=1/1b339139-326c-432f-90aa-15bf30f37be2.json
```

I can see that partition is getting loaded as -
account_id=acc-1234/year=2021/month=1/day=1

I am not sure what am I missing. I see in query result that  Data scanned: 0 KB

Comment: What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM historyrecordjson` return?

Comment: It is giving constraint violation since I have one injected type projection. I tried select count(*) from historyrecordjson where account_id ='acc-1234' and it is giving me as 0.

Comment: I tried partitioning separately for date and account_id, I was able to get records. But when I put both the partition in one table, got zero record.

Comment: Does it work for account_id and year? Just wondering if it only fails when it hits a month or day, since there might be a conflict over whether those values are zero-padded.

Answer (score 0):

The DDL that you are using is for a text delimited file where as your actual data in S3 is JSON data. Refer to https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde and create table with correct SerDe and definition for JSOn data.